# Cannot responsively shrink images past a certain size with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have three images positioned next to each other inside a  element and I am trying to shrink them with CSS.

```
<main>
    <img src="img1.png" alt="logo1" />
    <img src="img2.png" alt="logo2" />
    <img src="img3.png" alt="logo3" />
</main>
```

So far, I've managed to shrink them by setting their width and height to a percentage of vh and vw (vh when the orientation is portrait and vw when the orientation is landscape).

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    main img {
        width: 25vh;
        height: 25vh;
    }
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    main img {
        width: 25vw;
        height: 25vw;
    }
}
```

What I find frustrating, though, is that when the width of the viewport is less than a certain width (depending on the viewport height, too), the images do not shrink anymore and just position themselves below the others.

How can I shrink them to a tiny minimum size, so that the layout does not change?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `percentages` instead of `vh` and `vw` and also remove the media queries:

```
width: 25%;
```

Comment: Will this shrink my image by scaling both width and height? Will the image's width be a percentage of viewport height when the orientation is portrait and a percentage of viewport width when it's landscape?

Comment: It will set the width to 25% of the screen (both landscape and portrait). The height will be automatically adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<main>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt="logo1">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt="logo2">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt="logo3">
</main>
```

CSS

```
img { width: 30%; }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6krx9bte/

Notes:

- You may not need media queries for image re-sizing when you use percentage values.
- [The `<main>` element is not supported by Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/#search=main). Consider wrapping each `<img>` in a [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) element, and wrapping the group in a `<div>`, [`<article>`](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) or another element appropriate for the context.